# put request firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I am using real-time Database:

[image]

This is a put request in which users generate key onClick. This is working fine.

When a send user login from different device it just replaces the previous  user.

[image]

It does not add a new user history

```
import axios from 'axios';

const endPoint = 'https://*_hide_.firebaseio.com/userHistory.json/'


export const UserHistory = (data) => {
     let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
     return axios.put(endPoint,JSON.stringify(data), {
        headers :{ 
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': 'Bearer'+ token
      }
   }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `put` on a path replaces any existing value at that path with the value that you specify.

If you want to add a new child node under the path, you should use `post` instead of `put`.

If you want to merge the data you specify with any existing values at the path, you should use `patch` instead of `put`.

For more on this, also see the Firebase documentation on [writing data to the Realtime Database with its REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data).

Comment: I used put request the problem is that when a user purchase a new key a second time it will push a new object

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that means, which is why I intentionally described the different operations that are available in the REST API. You will either have to call `put` or `patch` on the correct path to update, or call `post` in the parent path to generate a new child.